# How do I know if the user has been redirected to another page? (Flutter, webview_flutter)

Tags: flutter, webview

I'm trying to make a implement a stripe payment system in my Flutter app. On this class it will opens a stripe payment page

```
class _MaxPageState extends State<MaxPage> {

  late final WebViewController controller;
  final String succeessPay = "https://link_to_success_pay";

  @override 
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = WebViewController()
    ..loadRequest(
      Uri.parse('https://link_to_my_stripe_payment'),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: ThemeColor.darkBlack,
        title: const Text(
          "Upgrade Account",
        ),
      ),
      body: WebViewWidget(
        controller: controller,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When the user successfully made a payment, it will automatically redirect the user to a new page, so how do I know if the payment has been succeeded by verifying if the user has been redirected to the success payment page?

webview_flutter version: 4.2.0

Comment: you need to get callback from the request, and then if the callback == payment success you can redirect to success payment page.

Comment: @rvng Yes I'm stuck on that part, I have no idea how to get get the callback.